# Twitter Bootstrap not render layout correctly when print on paper

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to layout a website template that could be used for printing using Twitter Bootstrap. My current code looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Loan</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <header>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <div style="text-align: left;">
                            <img src="logo-small.png" style="margin-top: 23px;">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 text-center">
                        <h4>Kingdom of Cambodia <br>Nation Religion King</h4>
                        <div style="text-align: center;"><img src="lineheader.png" /></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <div style="margin-left: -30px; margin-top: 95px; text-align:right;">Contract number÷ 123456789</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- end row -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
                        <h4>Letter Approval</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end col-sm-12 -->
            <div style="clear: both; height: 0px;"></div>
            <div class=""></div>
        </header>
        <section>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <p>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Microfinance Institution Plc. Has fulfilled the following terms and conditions: ÷
                    <p>
                        Khchei name John Michael Gender Male Nationality Cambodian, Cambodian identification number 123456789 and khchei Michael Alla Gender Female Cambodian Cambodian citizenship identification number 0938475626512 , address, current No. 12Eo, Str. 128, Sangkat Beoung Kang Kong II, Phnom Penh
                    </p>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-1">
                            Phone Number::
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-5">
                            <b>012 9999 2222</b>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-1">
                            Approval loan amount:
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-5">
                            <b>12,000.00 USD</b>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-1">
                            For the duration:
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-5">
                            <b>36 months</b>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-1">
                            For use in order:
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-5">
                            <b>Home Loan</b>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-1">
                            Interest rate per month:
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-5">
                            <b>1.6% %</b>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-1">
                            Monthly Payment:
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-5">
                            <b>300.00 USD</b>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-1">
                            Reward:
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-5">
                            <b>123.345$</b>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-1">
                            Assurances:
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-5">
                            <b>Hard title</b>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <p>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Microfinance Plc reserves the right to amend or terminate this loan at any time if an institution receives information that may cause it to be affected by the basis of which the loan is approved.
                    </p>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
    <script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

It looks fine on the browser, however when I print preview or print on A4 Paper, its layout is not the same as the browser.

On the browser it looks like this :
[image: Layout on browser]

When I print preview or print A4 paper, it looks very different:
[image: Layout on printed paper]

I don't know what is wrong. Maybe I am missing a style?

Comment: Could have to do with their use of `@media screen...` When printing anything wrapped in that will not be applied. Not sure, just trying to give you some leads.

Comment: @Don, thanks, I have no idea about this, don't know it is from different browser or printer machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap is "mobile first". Meaning it defaults to a mobile layout when some things aren't supported. I have a feeling this is happening when you're trying to print. If you change your columns classes to, for example, `col-xs-2` rather than `col-sm-2` this should tell the browser to render it as a 2 column span *even on mobile*. This should mean that it will default to this while printing. By using `sm` instead of `xs` you're saying on small screens, but not the smallest (mobile) screens, use a 2 column span, otherwise have it take up the whole width by default.

Essentially it's printing a mobile view so you need to change the "mobile" layout. You can read a bit about it [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries).

*Sidenote:* 
If you wanted to keep a mobile layout while also supporting printing, the only think I could think to do is add a `@media print{...` section to your own custom css file and do it all manually, but that's a bit much I would think. Alternately you could just copy what bootstrap has in their `sm` media query into it and go from there.

Comment: Thanks for the rabbit-hole. I've been working on making a webpage of mine printable (though I'm not using bootstrap), and this helped me a bit on that front too.

Comment: Thanks very much, it really helps. By changing class from `sm` to `xs`, the browser render my layout correctly. Though, I need to read for understand more about this. Thanks..